# Mention the energy conservation of falling ball in different mediums

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, potential-energy

Consider a plastic ball is being dropped off a certain height in different mediums like wood, floor of house, bed cover. In case of wood much more sound but less height. But in case of house floor you get more height and less sound. It states that the total amount of energy is same in both cases. That is what to be cause they have same potential energy. But consider I drop the plastic ball from the same height on bedcover (I mean same resultant height). I don't get equivalent sound or equivalent height from the experiment and nor the ball heats up nor heat something up (I know by touching both bed-cover and the ball) or create light energy. How do you describe the energy conservation with reference to the previous facts?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't heat anything up?

Comment: As @Shukhurov stated , in previous cases , the floors didn't get deformed  ,while the bed gets deformed . That deformation is result of some work used ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the ball is dropped on the bed cover, it does more work,
I mean force*distance product is larger.As a result the lost energy should turn into heat energy and energy required to change the shape of bed cover (also turns into heat energy after equilibrium). Maybe the change in temperature is not high enough to notice, but if you repeat the experiment many times, you should be able to notice it. At the same time, bed cover and ball are transferring heat energy to their surroundings.